# Unable to cast LINQ query to ObjectQuery

Tags: c#, linq

I get cast exception when I try to cast this simple LINQ select query

```
DbHw10Ent de = new DbHw10Ent();
var sales = from s in de.Sales
            select s;

        string sql = ((ObjectQuery)sales).ToTraceString();

        Console.WriteLine(sql);
```

Comment: Well what's the type of `de.Sales`, and why did you *expect* to be able to cast it to `ObjectQuery`? We don't have nearly enough information at the moment.

Comment: DbHw10Ent de = new DbHw10Ent();

it simply converts my sales LINQ to sql query format as string. like the video tutorial im following

Comment: That doesn't really help us much as we have no idea what `DbHw10Ent` is, or what the type of `Sales` is. This is the first time you've mentioned that it's LINQ to SQL, for a start. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: A linq returns by default a list object.  So try this : string sql = ((ObjectQuery)sales.FirstOrDefault()).ToTraceString();

Comment: @jdweng Actually, that is completely untrue. A LINQ expression normally returns either an `IEnumerable<>` or an `IQueryable<>`. Also not helpful with `.ToTraceString`.

Comment: Isn't a an IEnumerable<> and IQeryable<> list objects?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about `DbHw10Ent`, we can't say why it is failing.

However, you can try this, assuming `DbHw10Ent` is a `DataContext`:

```
    string sql = de.GetCommand(sales).CommandText;
```